# Web Element is not identified by Xpath containing a text for Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java.

Below is my html code:

```
<div id="servicetype-pp" class="z-combobox-popup " style="display: none; width: auto;">
    <ul id="servicetype-cave" class="z-combobox-content">
        <li id="zk_comp_140" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_141" class="z-comboitem">
            <span class="z-comboitem-image"></span>
            <span class="z-comboitem-text">Bill Generation Service</span>
        </li>
        <li id="zk_comp_142" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_143" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_144" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_145" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_146" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_147" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_148" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_149" class="z-comboitem">
        <li id="zk_comp_150" class="z-comboitem">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have defined a WebElement by xpath containing a particular text.

```
//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[contains(text(),'Bill Generation Service')]
```

It is not working. But, when I search with a single word, without any space, it is working fine.

```
//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[contains(text(),'Bill')] or
//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[contains(text(),'Generation')] or 
//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[contains(text(),'Service')]
```

It seems it is an issue with space.

Please help.

TIA.

Comment: Can you try searching using just the full text rather than contains api, for instance:-  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Bill Generation Service']"));

Comment: @AnupamSaini: Tried it. Didn't work. :(

Comment: @BhargavRaval what do you mean didn't work..Is there any exception??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: I tried these xpaths on Firepath & chrome developer tools. It did not identify the element. I tried running my script with      `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Payment Due Date']"));` It throws NoSuchElementException

Comment: u may try cssSelector here, if u wish i can give u cssSelector

Comment: @noor: Yes, please give me cssSelector.

Comment: make sure there is no frame for the element and class and id are static. try with the cssSelector : ui#servicetype-cave>li#zk_comp_141>span.z-comboitem-text and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `normalize-space()`

```
//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[contains(text()[normalize-space()], 'Bill Generation Service')]
```

Comment: @BhargavRaval you can also try `//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[normalize-space(.) = 'Bill Generation Service']`

Comment: and `//div[@id='servicetype-pp']//span[text()[normalize-space(.)] = 'Bill Generation Service']`

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `<div id="servicetype-pp" class="z-combobox-popup " style="display: none; width: auto;">` looks as invisible that's why you are not able to interact with the element, try as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("servicetype-pp"));
el = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';return arguments[0]", el);

//Now you can find your desire element
WebElement spanElement = el.findElement(".//span[contains(text(),'Bill Generation Service')]");

//Now do your further steps with this element
```

**Edited** :- If you are getting `NuSuchElementExcpetion` that means visibility is not the issue, It might be possible that this element is inside a `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding element as below :

```
 driver.switchTo().frame("frame name or id");

// Now go to find element 
WebElement spanElement = driver.findElement(".//span[contains(text(),'Bill Generation Service')]");
```

Comment: I don't think style is the issue here. I have other elements without `style=display: none`. For them also I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @BhargavRaval ok did you look for frame or iframe?? Make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe...

Comment: If you're getting nosuchelement may be this is inside any frame...check it and let me know..

Comment: The element is inside a frame & I already have switched to it. That's why it is working fine with single word, but it only throws error, when used text with space.

Comment: @BhargavRaval Then try with edited answer...use contains or normalize-space() in your xpath to avoid extra whitespaces..:)